# Using float in openCV shows all positive values, but using char will display both positive and negative values

Tags: opencv

I have a matrix in openCV, defined as

```
Mat X=Mat::zeros(300,300,CV_32F);
```

I have another matrix Y, that is also of the same form but contain positive as well as negative values. I want only positive values so I use the abs(Y) and store it in X.

```
X=abs(Y);
```

Now, on using

```
cout<<X.at<float>(i,j);
```

I am getting all positive values but if I do,

```
cout<<(int)X.at<char>(i,j);
```

I get both negative and positive values.

Comment: `X.at<char>(i,j);` is not legit if your Mat is CV_32F. if you would run a dbug build, you even would get a proper exception with the latter

Comment: `.at<char>` is no typecast, its a byte interpretation of your data. So you split up one float and use it as if it were 4 single char values.